# Webpacker/babel issue - can't load Uppy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, babeljs, webpacker, babel-plugin

I have pretty fresh rails application and I'm trying to add `uppy` file uploader to it. Unfortunately when requiring `@uppy/core` file I am presented with `Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'` error.

This error is caused by having both Ecma's `import` and CommonJS' `module.exports =` in a single file. I have checked uppy source code in `node_modules` to find that the offending file does not have `import` - however it is present in a version received by the browser, just under `"use_strict"`:

```
import _regeneratorRuntime from "@babel/runtime/regenerator";
```

This suggests that babel plugin decided to inject `import` statement into a CommonJS file, making it impossible to load that file.

Removing the `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'` from babel.config.js resolved the issue - but it also broke `@babel/preset-env`  which expects global regenerationRuntime object.

I have created a minimal reproduction application here: https://github.com/BroiSatse/babel-issue. It is a fresh installation of rails, no js config changes except for `@uppy/core` dependency with single route to dummy action and `import Uppy from '@uppy/core'` in webpack/packs/application.js`.

Any help appreciated, I don't even know where to raise that issue on github.